# How to serve a directory and its files and subdirectories with jetty as included in solr?

Tags: solr, jetty

I'm using `solr-6.4.1` on Windows 7. `solr` is installed under `W:\solr-6.4.1`
and I want to serve static files being in a directory outside solr's structure, and ideally in another volume e.g. `Z:\path\to\files`.

Should I configure it in `W:\solr-6.4.1\server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml`?

What (minimal) directives are necessary to serve a directory outside `W:\solr-6.4.1` without conflicting with the rest of the configuration for solr/jetty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it this way:

- create a file called W:\solr-6.4.1\server\contexts\staticfiles.xml
- its contents should be:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
  <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
    <Set name="contextPath">/scratch</Set>
    <Set name="handler">
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
        <Set name="resourceBase">Z:\path\to\files</Set>
        <Set name="directoriesListed">true</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>
  </Configure>
  ```
- restart solr, and you should be able to access static files at http://localhost:8983/scratch/yourfile.txt

So, no need to touch solr webapp. On the other hand, this might not work in the future, you cannot assume jetty will be used, it's an implementation detail as this point.